# React Props components not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following one of the tutorials when this issue came up. I am using React js with Firebase Cloud Firestore. In the code, the component called Post is not rendering on the screen! There is no error shown either. No warnings !
Here's the code of Feed.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TweetBox from "./TweetBox";
import Post from "./Post";
import "./Feed.css";
import db from "./firebase";
import FlipMove from "react-flip-move";

function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="feed__header">
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>


      <FlipMove>
        {posts &&
          posts.map((post) => {
            <Post
              key={post.text}
              displayName={post.displayName}
              userName={post.userName}
              verified={post.verified}
              text={post.text}
              avatar={post.avatar}
              image={post.image}
            />;
          })}
      </FlipMove>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

Code of Post.js

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import "./Post.css";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import VerifiedUserIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VerifiedUser";
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleOutline";
import RepeatIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Repeat";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";
import PublishIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Publish";

const Post = forwardRef(
  ({ displayName, userName, verified, text, image, avatar }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div className="post" ref={ref}>
        <div className="post__avatar">
          <Avatar src={avatar} />
        </div>
        <div className="post__body">
          <div className="post__header">
            <div className="post__headerText">
              <h3>
                {displayName}{" "}
                <span className="post__headerSpecial">
                  {verified && <VerifiedUserIcon className="post__badge" />} @
                  {userName}
                </span>
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div className="post__headerDescription">
              <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img src={image} alt="" />
          <div className="post__footer">
            <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon fontSize="small" />
            <RepeatIcon fontSize="small" />
            <FavoriteBorderIcon fontSize="small" />
            <PublishIcon fontSize="small" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Post;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: probably post is empty, can you console log this `snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())`?

Comment: I did that. It correctly gave all the value

Comment: is it array of objects?

Comment: Yes. It is array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` is missing.

```
posts.map((post) => {
            return <Post
              key={post.text}
              displayName={post.displayName}
              userName={post.userName}
              verified={post.verified}
              text={post.text}
              avatar={post.avatar}
              image={post.image}
            />;
})}
```

if you don't wanna write `return`, you can wrap your component with `()`

```
posts.map((post) => (<Post //your other props here/>))}
```